# R creates empty pdf from ggplot graphic when I source script but not when I run it

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an R script that produces several graphics, I run into this problem that with at least some of these graphics, when I source the script the pdf file that is supposed to have the graphic has no pages.  However when I run the file from the beginning simply running every line, I get the desired graph.  I do not understand the problem and I couldn't find someone with precisely the same problem upon searching.

My code outputting the graphic in question (which is not the first graphic produced by the script) is roughly as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
container$C <- as.factor(container$C)

pdf("../dataVis/AC.pdf")
p <- ggplot(container, aes(x = A*1000)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = C), bins = 24) +
  xlab("A") +
  ylab("Frequency") +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 18), axis.title = element_text(size = 18),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 18), axis.text = element_text(size = 18)) +
  xlim(c(0, 2.5))
p$labels$fill <- "C"
p
dev.off()
```

Here's the session info after sourcing the file in question:

```
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19043)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_3.3.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] rstudioapi_0.13    magrittr_2.0.2     tidyselect_1.1.2   munsell_0.5.0      mise_0.1.0        
 [6] colorspace_1.4-1   R6_2.5.1           rlang_1.0.1        fansi_1.0.2        dplyr_1.0.8       
[11] tools_4.0.0        grid_4.0.0         data.table_1.13.0  gtable_0.3.0       utf8_1.2.2        
[16] cli_3.2.0          DBI_1.1.2          withr_2.4.3        ellipsis_0.3.2     matrixStats_0.57.0
[21] digest_0.6.29      assertthat_0.2.1   tibble_3.1.6       lifecycle_1.0.1    crayon_1.5.0      
[26] farver_2.1.0       purrr_0.3.4        vctrs_0.3.8        glue_1.6.1         labeling_0.4.2    
[31] compiler_4.0.0     pillar_1.7.0       generics_0.1.2     scales_1.1.1       pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

My only hypothesis is that it is something to do with how source() is handled by R that prevents this graphic from being produced correctly, and possibly that it has something to do with ggplot2.  I am honestly not sure how to approach a problem that only shows up when I source and not when I run the script.

Comment: Try replacing `p` with `print(p)`? Or sourcing with `source(print.eval = TRUE)`? See `?print.ggplot`.

Comment: See R FAQ: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f